# how to generate authentication token after spring security login

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, token

I want to generate an authentication token after a successful login using spring security authentication.Here is what I was thinking of-

a) Have an AES key generated and stored.

b) encrypt the username + timestamp with this AES key (you my have to base64 encode after this step to avoid any special characters). This will be your user token.

c) sign this token with an HMAC key (again store this in keystore).

d) send the token along with the signature (use ; as the delimiter).

e) store the token which you got in step c against the username in the DB.

I don't know how to implement the above.After generating the token as above I want to send this in the response header of the rest request response service.Also i have to send some json data along with the response header.I have a server controller where the request comes so i likes to get the generated token in my controller.Please help me to do this.

Comment: Did you think about OAuth? http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/

Comment: @JIMI yes.But i didn't understood how to implement that.Also its concept is not clear from the documentation and the source code are too complicated for me to understand as a beginner.

Comment: I understand that it might be uneasy to grasp spring-oauth, but I would still recommend you to check out the tutorial: [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) and samples + source codes. It should give you an idea of how things work. It is good to know how things work and implementing them yourself is the best way to learn that but you will have a hard time doing that right now as a beginner.

Comment: @JIMI everyone says about web application.Our scenario is for a android application where the client communicate with the server using rest which send and retrieve data as json and all its controlled by a controller at the server end.Everyone telling about issuing a token after authentication but no one says how this token is available for our controller.I completely lost after reading so much of tutorial about spring security,Oath,token management,...

Comment: out of curiousity - what did u end up with? did u use oAuth spec (not sure this is the right thing for you...) I have implemented similar thing (the encoding and encryption, https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample/tree/master/common-crypto)